# How to read Outlook Web App calendar events in a script (win10)?

Tags: outlook-web-app

I'd like to read events for a user in outlook web app calendar preferable 
with python3.x if possible but I'm also open to other script languages.

The calendar is on https://profimailer.de/owa/#path=/calendar 
but I think there's no difference to the following one
https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/calendar/, correct?

Well I never did this, so I've got no idea where to start with...
Is there an open source API for this purpose?

Thanks